# Dired invert selection

Tags: emacs, dired

I want to mark all files currently unmarked and simultaneously unmark all marked files. How do I do it?

Let's say I have a directory with *.png and and other formats. I want to filter only PNGs. Say, I did: <kbd>% d</kbd>`.png` and now want to select the rest, but not the PNG?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you used <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to select the files (`dired-flag-file-deletion`), they are considered 
[*flagged*, not marked](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marks-vs-Flags.html). To mark files, you may use <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> (`dired-mark`). The command <kbd>t</kbd> toggles the marked files (`dired-toggle-marks`); this was mentioned by event_jr's answer. To convert files from flagged to marked, use the command <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> (`dired-change-marks`).

It seems the only command that operates on flagged files is <kbd>x</kbd>, which deletes them ([`dired-do-flagged-delete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Deletion.html)). The same can be achieved on marked files with <kbd>D</kbd> ([`dired-do-delete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html)), and you can do much more on marked files, such as <kbd>R</kbd> ([`dired-do-rename`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html)). So apparently the only advantage of flagging are the [convenient commands to flag "garbage" files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Flagging-Many-Files.html), which you may use and then convert the flags to marks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>t</kbd> .................................... for toggle

Comment: Not sure about the special action flags.  I just rarely use them.  I use <kbd>D</kbd> on marked files.

Comment: `% d` _flags_ for deletion and `% m` _marks_ files; see [this manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marks-vs-Flags.html). You may try `* c D *` to convert flags to marks and then use `t` for toggle.

Comment: @event_jr: I think a new answer would seem a bit unfair, since I learned the command `t` from your answer.